# How to go about this implementation of query

Tags: sql, sql-server

My database table are as follow

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[vProduct](
[nId] [int] NOT NULL, //Primary key
[sName] [varchar](255) NULL

  )

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[vProductLanguage](
[kProduct] [int] NOT NULL,
[kLanguage] [int] NOT NULL  //Foriegn key to table vLanguage
 ) 


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[vLanguage](
[nId] [int] NOT NULL, //Primary key
[sName] [varchar](50) NULL,
[language] [char](2) NULL
  )
```

Table vProduct has relation to vProductLanguage on vProduct.nId = vProductLanguage.kLanguage

Table vProductLanguage has relation to vLanguage on vProductLanguage.kLanguage = vLanguage.nid

So its like table vProductLanguage will have languages which are being selected

Rows will be like image below

```
Table vProduct
```

[image: vProduct]

```
Table vProductLanguage
```

[image: vProductLanguage]

```
Table vLanguage
```

[image: vLanguage]

What i want is select all Languages from table vLanguage and selected languages from table vProductLanguage. This will be associated with table vProduct.
I tried below query but it only returns me the languages which are associated with product.

```
select * from 
      vProductLanguage 
           left join vLanguage on vProductLanguage.kLanguage = vLanguage.nId
       left join vProduct on vProductLanguage.kProduct = vProduct.nId
Where vProduct.nId = 1
```

I want to select all the rows from table vLanguage and table vProductLanguage.

Hope i made my question clear.

Comment: do i need to make union query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to start your `JOIN` with the `vLanguage` table first:

```
select *
from vLanguage l
left join vProductLanguage pl
  on l.nid = pl.kLanguage
left join vProduct p
  on pl.kProduct = p.nid
  and p.nid = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26ef8/3).

This will return all rows from the `vLanguage` table and any matching rows from the `vProductLanguage` table.  .

If you have more than one `vProduct` then you can rewrite the query slightly to:

```
select *
from vLanguage l
left join
(
  select pl.kLanguage, 
    p.nid,
    p.sName
  from vProductLanguage pl
  left join vProduct p
    on pl.kProduct = p.nid
  where p.nid = 1
) p
  on l.nid = p.kLanguage
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3a5045/3)

Comment: but you didnt added where clause? i tried and it only returns 4 records. I need those 4 records and remaining records from vLanguage table. see i updated fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26ef8/2

Comment: @AshReva sorry I missed the `WHERE` clause, the where filter will be applied to the `JOIN` condition. See my edit

Comment: You just added "and" clause. Curious to know why it doesnt work with Where clause. Also the way we have created query is ok or not?

Comment: @AshReva If you place that filter in the `WHERE` clause then it acts like an `INNER JOIN` which is not the result that you want.  You want to return all `vLanguage` rows and the `vProduct` rows with the correct `nid`.  By placing the filter on the join, then you will return the correct result from both tables.

Comment: I am not able to understand that this works in sql fiddle but on my sql server 2008 it returns me all the rows from vProduct table. It is just ignoring condition "and p.nid = 1" Any idea?

Comment: @AshReva it should work the same see this sql server 2012 demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/26ef8/1.  Can you edit the fiddle with some additional data?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24284/discussion-between-ashreva-and-bluefeet)

Comment: see updated fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3a5045/1 
This wont work if i add one more Product in vProduct table

Comment: in the kLanguage field i am getting NULL. i wanted 0 instead so i tried using isNull function but it doesnt return me 0. see updated fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3a5045/6  I am not sure if i should open new question for this. if its too simple for you then help me here or if you want me to open new question then let me know

Comment: @AshReva thanks, but unfortunately you are limited to an upvote and and accept. :)